# -[UIBezierPath moveToPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, selector, sigabrt, uibezierpath

When I am running my application I am getting the following exception

-[UIBezierPath moveToPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e0fcc0

and the app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Either UIBezierPath variable holds something else, something other than UIBezierPath; OR you are running it [under iOS 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW2).

Comment: I haven't used that variable in my entire project. And this crash is completely random. And I am running it in iOS 5.1

Comment: I probably dint notice that I tried to run one more time and I dint get that crash. Probability of occurrence is 3/10

Comment: Sometimes XCode acts bizarre. You may want to clear builds, clear derived data, reset iOS simulator, restart XCode and run fresh to get rid of every such occurrences. However this specific message tells that you are inadvertently performing something which is causing this crash.